# How to write a variable value in a text file with php

Tags: php

I have a problem with a php code. It's a simple web page hosted on my computer with two buttons and a text box. When I click + or - button the number in text box increase or decrease. Everything works as is suppose to, except when I want to write the textBox.value into a text file using php code. The result is something like "value = textBox.value" when it should be something like "value = 0". Thank you.
The code is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<input id="increaseNumber" type="button" value="+" style="font-size:24pt; width: 50px; height: 50px;"><br>
<input id="textBox" type="text" value="0" style="font-size:24pt; width: 40px; height: 40px;">
<label style="font-size:24pt;">&#8451;</label><br>
<input id="decreaseNumber" type="button" value="-" style="font-size:24pt; width: 50px; height: 50px;"><br>

<script>

decreaseNumber.onclick = function() {
   textBox.value = parseInt(textBox.value) -1
}
increaseNumber.onclick = function() {
   textBox.value = parseInt(textBox.value) + 1
}

</script>

<?php
$myfile = fopen("/home/pi/test/test.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");

$txt = "value = ";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
$v = textBox.value;
fwrite($myfile, $v);
fclose($myfile);
?> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: errors, if any? is it writing to that file? check you console also

Comment: `$v = textBox.value;` doesn't look like PHP. Error reporting would've told you that too.

Comment: ^ true and error reporting would have thrown them undefined constant notices. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Brief Explanation:**

You are trying to combine two separate languages as if both were client-side "as needed" scripting languages.

Javascript is client-side, and as such, will run based on event listeners or any other defined parameters. PHP is server-side, and as such, will run when the file is parsed. This means that your PHP is already processed and out of the picture by the time the Javascript even comes into the picture.

**What is happening in your script presently:**

The file is parsed, PHP is identified, and runs first. Immediately upon running, the file gets written to. PHP defaults to the text-value of "textBox.value" as it is not an actual variable (which would be preceded with $ if it were). In all honesty, it *should* be returning an error that "textBox.value" means nothing, essentially (PHP is not strict, so it makes a lot of assumptions). It's not, however, because it's assuming you are referencing a Constant. After the PHP is processed, the DOM is processed and sent to the browser. The PHP does not even exist at this point and has been stripped away from the DOM (rightfully so - you'd NEVER want PHP to be visible to a client).

**What to do:**

You cannot run this PHP snippet every time you want to increment/decrement the value with the PHP being inside of the same file (at least not without a form submit, or something to "catch" the request -- my response will be based on the fact that you simply want it to write when clicking, instead of submitting a form every time). You must change your code. One thing I'd suggest is placing the PHP inside of its own file. Then, upon incrementing/decrementing the value, you use AJAX to actually hit that file (thus triggering a file write).

**Example:**

*index.html*:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<input id="increaseNumber" type="button" value="+" style="font-size:24pt; width: 50px; height: 50px;"><br>
<input id="textBox" type="text" value="0" style="font-size:24pt; width: 40px; height: 40px;">
<label style="font-size:24pt;">&#8451;</label><br>
<input id="decreaseNumber" type="button" value="-" style="font-size:24pt; width: 50px; height: 50px;"><br>

<script>

$("#decreaseNumber").on("click", function() {
   $("#textBox").val(parseInt($("#textBox").val()) -1);
   writeToFile($("#textBox").val());
})
$("#increaseNumber").on("click", function() {
   $("#textBox").val(parseInt($("#textBox").val()) +1);
   writeToFile($("#textBox").val());
})

function writeToFile(value){

    $.ajax({
        url: 'write.php?v=' + value,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(ret){
            alert('Success!');
        },
        error: function(ret){
            alert('Error!');
        }
    });

}


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

*write.php*:

```
<?php
$myfile = fopen("/home/pi/test/test.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");

$txt = "value = " . $_GET['v'];
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

**Note the Changes:**

I am using JQuery in my example. I apologize if you wanted strictly native Javascript.

Also please note, I changed the PHP. You had two writes, which was unnecessary and would take more time. File Input/Output is costly, and should be used minimally. In fact, in this example, I'd personally have just written to a database. However, you did not ask for a separate solution, so I simply provided an example similar to what you had written.

**Random Thoughts**

You can use decrement/increment instead of what you're doing as well. Like so:

```
<script>

decreaseNumber.onclick = function() {
    textBox.value--;
    alert(textBox.value);
}
increaseNumber.onclick = function() {
    textBox.value++;
    alert(textBox.value);
}

</script>
```

Comment: Your example works best for what I need, but every time I execute the code it's gives me "Error" and never "Success", even if everything works as is suppose to. So I deleted ajax alerts and now it's perfect. Thank you very much.

Comment: No problem at all! You could also go more in-depth with this and have some error responses right in the AJAX. For example, if it cannot open the file, you'd receive a response instead of it just dying (which using AJAX is sometimes hard to debug if you're not watching the "Network" tab in developer tools). I'd be happy to edit this post to show how to accomplish that if you'd like to see it.

Answer (score 0):

To make php do this, you would need to submit the form. You can either do this via ajax or a normal post submit.

I've modified your code to work on a basic post submit.
Please read up on what a post method is.

I've had to make tiny changes in your HTML as well, and php. 
I've commented them for ease.

You cannot combine two different languages to work together, not in this case at least. You could assign values from PHP to JAVASCRIPT variables, but not the other way around.

PHP has the ability to read values of input fields as long as they are submitted.
If you would like for PHP to write to the file every time the number is increased or decreased, you will have to do an ajax request to a php script on those particular events to get this done.(onClick)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST')
{
    $myfile = fopen("/home/pi/test/test.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");

    //You dont need to write twice, you can use both values in one single variable and write once
    //added whitespce \r\n for line break
    $v = $_POST['textbox'];
    $txt = "value = $v";
    fwrite($myfile, $txt);
    fclose($myfile);
    echo "written to file";
}
?> 
<html>
<body>
<!--Made this a form so it can be submit to php-->
<!--Read about POST method-->
<form method="POST" action="">
<input id="increaseNumber" type="button" value="+" style="font-size:24pt; width: 50px; height: 50px;"><br>
<!-- Add the name attribute so php can read the value -->
<input  name ='textbox' id="textBox" type="text" value="0" style="font-size:24pt; width: 40px; height: 40px;">
<label style="font-size:24pt;">&#8451;</label><br>
<input id="decreaseNumber" type="button" value="-" style="font-size:24pt; width: 50px; height: 50px;"><br>
<input type='submit' value='Submit'/>
</form>
<script>

decreaseNumber.onclick = function() {
   textBox.value = parseInt(textBox.value) -1
}
increaseNumber.onclick = function() {
   textBox.value = parseInt(textBox.value) + 1
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**LINKS THAT WILL BE USEFUL TO YOU**

$_POST - http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

PHP FORM HANDLING - http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

AJAX REQUESTS - http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp

Answer (score 0):

Here, you are getting value in javascript easily and in php if you want to get values then you have to post the form or send through parameters in URL.Here are some ways to passing data in php :
- Passing PHP variables with $_POST
- Passing PHP variables in links with $_GET
- Passing PHP variables without POST or GET | $_SESSION
- Passing PHP variables arrays from one page to another
- Passing PHP COOKIE variables

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
<input id="increaseNumber" type="button" value="+" style="font-size:24pt; width: 50px; height: 50px;"><br>
<input id="textBox" type="text" value="0" name="textBox" style="font-size:24pt; width: 40px; height: 40px;">
<label style="font-size:24pt;">&#8451;</label><br>
<input id="decreaseNumber" type="button" value="-" style="font-size:24pt; width: 50px; height: 50px;"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Write To File">
</form>
<script>

decreaseNumber.onclick = function() {
   textBox.value = parseInt(textBox.value) -1
}
increaseNumber.onclick = function() {
   textBox.value = parseInt(textBox.value) + 1
}

</script>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $myfile = fopen("/home/pi/test/test.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");

    $txt = "value = ";
    fwrite($myfile, $txt);
    $v = $_POST['textBox'];
    fwrite($myfile, $v);
    fclose($myfile);
}
?> 

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing things up and it won't work like this.

First off, enclose your input boxes inside a `<form>` pointing to the PHP file that will handle the increase / decrease function, and write it to the test.txt file:

```
<form id="handler" method="post" action="handler.php">
    <!-- Your input elements here -->
</form>
```

Also, you'll need to add the attribute `name` to your `textBox` element, you may call it `nvalue`, in example.

Second, your click event listeners are invalid. The correct to set them is:

```
document.getElementById("decreaseNumber").addEventListener("click", function() {
   document.getElementById("textBox.value").value--;
   document.getElementById("handler").submit();
});
```

The same goes for `increaseeNumber`

Third, put your php in your new `handler.php` file. Get the increase/decrease value with `$_POST['nvalue']`. Write this value to the file.

Note: You may also use AJAX for this, but it's a little more advanced and you'll also probably need a JS library like jQuery.

Note 2: You can redirect back from `handler.php` to your form page after updating `test.txt` file by using php `header()` function.

Note 3: You can make your `<input id="textBox">` to show the current value  in the file `test.txt` by loading it above and echoing `value = "<?php echo  $nvalue; ?>"`, of course, $nvalue is gotten using `fread()` or similar.